# how to get the char inbetween hyphen

Tags: sql

```
qa-raj-ra
```

I want to get `raj` from the above string.

Length of the character in between hyphen may vary.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc. ? Also we need to see your efforts (queries you've tried) before asking the question.

Comment: search on net for substring function for your RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only part of your string, you can use the inbuilt `SPLIT` function in MS SQL Server.
Given the delimiter, it will split the string for you.

This query below might help return the required result;

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @delimiter CHAR(1),
        @start INT,
        @end INT 

create TABLE #output (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX))  

SET @string = 'qa-raj-ra'
SET @delimiter = '-'

    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO #output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

       END  

SELECT splitdata FROM #output  
WHERE  ID = 2
```

For a better use, you can put the query into a stored procedure and use `@string` as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a quick and nasty way of getting your result via a query (on MySQL).

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT('qa-raj-ra',LENGTH('qa-raj-ra')-INSTR('qa-raj-ra','-')),
     INSTR(RIGHT('qa-raj-ra',LENGTH('qa-raj-ra')-INSTR('qa-raj-ra','-')),'-')-1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/48020

You can replace the hard coded string with whatever you want and it will return the text between the two hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can use `string_to_array()`

```
select (string_to_array('qa-raj-ra', '-'))[2]
```